# AngularFire2 db.collection Adds key 2 Times

Tags: firebase, angular5, angularfire2

I followed this guide to [create a upload-component for Angular5 with AngularFire2](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firebase-storage-with-angularfire-dropzone-file-uploader/).

At the end of the Video he showed a code snippet that allows adding a url path to any other database url.

```js
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    tap(snap => {
        console.log(snap);
        if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
            // Update firestore on completion
            this.db.collection('photos').add({ path, size: snap.totalBytes }).then();
        }
    })
);
```

This creates a url entry to photos, but it does it 2 times. Any idea how this can be? Each upload he creates 2 random keys with exactly same content inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Add to collection in **downloadURL()**

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage)

uploadFile(file){
  const filePath = 'images/' + this.docRef + '/';
  const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

  task.percentageChanges().subscribe(per => {
    console.log(per);
  });

  task.downloadURL().subscribe(url => {
    console.log(url);
    this.db.collection('photos').add('required data')
  }
}
```

Comment: I Dont know why, but this.db.collection.add(); crates for me every time 2 entries in database... Is this maybe a angularfire2 bug?

Comment: may be! one time for completion and another time while fetching the link also the (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) will be satisified and executed. but not sure.